# Sane(r) way to get character-encoding of the CLI in Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, command-line, foundation

I was writing a CLI-Tool for Mac OS X (10.5+) that has to deal with command-line arguments which are very likely to contain non-ASCII characters.

For further processing, I convert these arguments using +[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:].

My problem is, that I couldn't find good information on how to determine the character-encoding used by the shell in which said cli-tool is running in.
What I came up with as a solution is the following:

```
NSDictionary *environment = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
NSString *ianaName = [[environment objectForKey:@"LANG"] pathExtension];
NSStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(
  CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding( (CFStringRef)ianaName ) );

NSString *someArgument = [NSString stringWithCString:argv[someIndex] encoding:encoding];
```

I find that a little crude, however -- which makes me think that I missed out something obvious...but what?

Is there a saner/cleaner way of achieving essentially the same?

Thanks in advance

D

Comment: For clarification:

The tool I wrote is *not* a GUI program, but a command-line-tool wich links against `Foundation.h`; the string-conversion, that is going on is from C-string to `NSString`.

The encoding therefore depends on the settings of the command-line-environment. It can easily be changed through e.g. the preferences of Terminal.app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turns out there seems to be none!

As Yuji pointed out, the underlying encoding of filenames is UTF-8, no matter what. Therefore, one needed to handle **two scenarios**:

1. Arguments that are typed in, character for character, by the user.
2. Arguments that are tab-completed or the output of commands like `ls`, as they do not convert any characters.

The second case is simply covered by the assumption of UTF-8.

The first case, however, is problematic:

- On Mac OS 10.6, $LANG contains the IANA-name of the used encoding like `de_DE.IANA_NAME`.
- Prior to Snow Leopard, *this is not the case* for **charsets other than UTF-8!**

I didn't test each and every charset I could think of, but none of the european ones were included. Instead, $LANG only was the language-locale (`de_DE` in my case)!

Since the results of calling `+[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]` with an incorrect encoding **[are undefined](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithCString:encoding:)**, you cannot safely assume that it will return `nil` in that case* (if eg. it's ASCII-only, it might work perfectly fine!).

What adds to the overall mess is that `$LANG` **is not guarateed** to be around, anyway: There's a checkbox in Terminal.app's preferences, that enables a user to not set `$LANG` at all (not to speak of X11.app which doesn't seem to handle any non-ASCII input...).

So what's left:

1. Check for presence of `$LANG`. If it's not set, Goto:4!
2. Check if `$LANG` contains information on the encoding. If it doesn't, Goto:4!
3. Check if the encoding you find there is UTF-8. If it is Goto:6, else...
4. If `argc` is greater than 2 and `[[NSString stringWithCString: argv[0] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] isEqualToString: yourForceUTFArgumentFlag]`, print that you are forcing UTF-8 now and Goto 6. If not:
5. Assume you don't know anything, issue a warning that your user should set the Terminal encoding to UTF-8 and may consider passing `yourForceUTFArgumentFlag` as the first argument and **exit()**.
6. Assume UTF-8 and do what you have to...

Sounds shitty? That's because it is, but I can't think of any **saner** way of doing it.

---

One further note though:
If you are using UTF-8 as an encoding, stringWithCString:encoding: returns nil whenever it encounters non-ASCII characters in a C-String that is *not* encoded in UTF-8.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what the non-asciiness comes from.

1. In OS X, the environment variable `LANG` does **not** reflect the choice of language in the GUI. Very few people will set `LANG` at the command line.
2. The choice of the "system encoding" at the GUI is stored in `~/.CFUserTextEncoding`, and can be obtained by `CFStringGetSystemEncoding`, see this [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001211-CH201-F11150).
3. That said, this "system encoding" is **rarely used** except in a very old, non-unicode aware softwares. Any sane Cocoa program uses just Unicode and nothing else.
4. In particular, the file path at the level of Cocoa is always encoded in (a variant of) UTF-8. So, to get an `NSString` from a C string, use

   ```
    NSString*string=[NSString stirngWithCString:cString encoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
   ```

   and to get a C-string for the file path from an `NSString`, use

   ```
    char*path=[string fileSystemRepresentation];
   ```

   Here it is recommended not to use just `[string UTF8String]`, due to the subtlety, see this [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#UnicodeSubtleties).
5. So, I recommend you not to care about the encoding and just assume UTF-8.
6. That said, there might be a very small number of people who sets `LANG` on the command line, and you might want to take care of them.   Then, what you did is the only thing I can come up with.

Comment: I didn't directly commented 'cause I hoped for additional answers ;-)
Well, the non-asciiness is inherent in that my users are German and the command-line arguments are filenames. More so, these files will likely be given the names of people, so I have to deal with 'Weißmüller', 'Ölmann' and the likes. Since this is *not* a GUI app but a command-line tool, CFStringGetSystemEncoding just can't cut it, as it has nothing to do with what eg. Terminal.app is using (personally, I use UTF-8 *most of the time* in Terminal but ~/.CFUserTextEncoding indicates  the default 'MacRoman').

Comment: One more thing... Although it's not that relevant to what I currently am doing, thanks for the mention of TN1150, as I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: ??? Filenames on OS X are inherently UTF-8 at the level of BSD, independent of the choice of the encoding in Terminal's preference.  (Or at least that's the case with Japanese. There are many pre-unicode Japanese encodings, but none is used in the file system. Contents of the file are different story.) It might be different if you mount an NSF share on UNIX boxes, but that's a rare case... Is the situation different with German?

Comment: Ah, are you wondering the case where a user might type the file name directly on the Terminal in non-unicode encodings? If so, that's a disaster waiting to happen. What if the output of `ls` is given to your command-line program as an argument? That will surely contain UTF-8. Translating that C-string into NSString in the other encoding will be a failure. I think the only sane choice here is to prompt the user to change the Terminal encoding to UTF8.

Comment: Yep, that's the thing. Didn't have much time to check what you were saying 'til now, but it *looks* as if you're right: I wrote a small test-tool that does nothing than NSLogging the arguments I pass it. If I `./CLIEncodingTest \`ls FOLDER_WITH_UMLAUT_FILES\``, +[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:] returns nil for each entry that contains "special"characters in its file-name.

Comment: I'm sure I'm right :) As a Japanese (with multiple pre-Unicode encodings) I struggled with it a few years ago when I switched to Mac. I found that to be the only sane approach...

Comment: Been testing some more and found out that in 10.5.8, the encoding is *not set* in $LANG when it differs from the default UTF-8 (as opposed to 10.6.2 and 10.6.3) anyway... AAAAAAAAAAAAAARGGGGGGGGHHH! Okay: That's it! English: 1, Me(German): 0 -- as opposed to last weeks GER: 4, ENG: 1, I guess ;-)

Is it okay with you if I factor your further comments and my findings into a new answer as your original one didn't fit that well?

Comment: Yeah go ahead. My recommendation for Terminal internationalization is always the same for everyone: convince others to just stick to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Can’t you just use `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments]`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @IlijaDimov How does it not answer the question? The poster needed to decode command-line arguments that were passed to the program. `NSProcessInfo` already deals with the problem of decoding argument and environment strings.

Comment: D’oh! I suppose I could — and _should_ — have used just that.Well, what can I say: I was young and inexperienced